# reactjs passing value to useEffect from useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am building a reactjs app

I want to get my user id from redux state

using useSelector and pass it to useEffect

My code

UserReducer

```
export function userReducer(state = { token: "", user: {} }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return action.payload;
    case "LOGOUT":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

ViewTransaction.jsx

```
const ViewTransaction = () => {
  const user_id = useSelector((state) => state.user.user.id);
  const params = useParams();

   useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      PendingServices.getPendingTransaction(
        `localhost:8000/user/transaction/pending/get-transaction/${params.id}?user_id=${user_id}`
      )
        .then((response) => {})
        .catch((error) => {})
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);
   return (
        <div>transaction</div>
   )
}

export default ViewTransaction;
```

user_id is showing undefined.

Comment: `state.user.user.id` is initially undefined. Your `useEffect` hook is missing dependencies, specifically the `user_id` and `params.id`. When do you want this request/asynchronous call to be made?

Comment: Where did you define user_id in reducer?

Comment: @cooskun is coming from the useSelector

Comment: When I am looking at your state, the user doesn't have an id. Did you patch it somewhere else?

Comment: @cooskun I have updated my question. the id is coming from the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `user_id` in the `useEffect`'s dependency array and check if it's defined or not. Because on first render it's undefined because redux didn't provided it yet.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   if(user_id){
      setLoading(true);
      PendingServices.getPendingTransaction(
        `localhost:8000/user/transaction/pending/get-transaction/${params.id}?user_id=${user_id}`
      )
        .then((response) => {})
        .catch((error) => {})
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
   }
    }, [user_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Drew wrote in the comment above your dependency array is missing variables. React tries to be smart about not calling hooks in vain, and by passing it no dependencies you let it assume that the call to the method in useEffect will always be the same, and that it can cache and reuse the result of the invocation. Since user_id is undefined initially, when no one have logged in, the result of useEffect with an undefined user is cached.

By adding user_id and params.id in the dep array you're telling React that "each time these variables change, the result of the method should also change", so it will invalidate the cached useEffect result and run the method again.

I'd recommend using this eslint plugin to automatically help catch these cases: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks